# How do one request with 2 request SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, join, request

i have some problem to do an JOIN with two SQL request

request 1:

```
SELECT *
FROM `tableA` 
INNER JOIN tableB
ON tableA.products_id=tableB.products_id
LEFT JOIN tableC
ON tableB.products_id=tableC.products_id
LEFT JOIN tableD AS CD
ON CD.categories_id=tableC.categories_id
WHERE orders_id >=80000 AND orders_id <=80010 GROUP BY orders_id
```

Request 2:

```
SELECT *     
FROM `tableA` AS OP
LEFT JOIN tableE AS PTP
ON OP.products_id=PTP.products_id

LEFT JOIN tableD AS CD
ON PTP.categories_id=CD.categories_id

WHERE  orders_id >=80000 AND orders_id <=80010 GROUP BY orders_id
```

**it's is possible to do only ONE request with those two request ? or it's just impossible?
thanks for any help you can give**

Comment: I removed the sql-server tag because the syntax is MySQL.  Perhaps you should explain what you want to do, because it is not at all clear.  For instance, the two queries would appear to return different columns, so they could not be combined into a single query.

Comment: thanks you for edit this early, that must help.
(i just try explain what my problem with easy post because my english not very well and dont want to use an translate) , thanks you and other for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get what you are trying to do, but my guess was that you wanted to have the data from tableE (PTP) included in your first query too. In that is the case you can do it like:

```
        SELECT 
             *
        FROM 
            `tableA` 
        INNER JOIN 
            `tableB` ON (`tableA`.`products_id` = `tableB`.`products_id`)
        LEFT JOIN 
            `tableE` AS `PTP` ON (`tableA`.`products_id` = `PTP`.`products_id`)
        LEFT JOIN 
            `tableC` ON (`tableB`.`products_id` = `tableC`.`products_id`)
        LEFT JOIN 
            `tableD` AS `CD` ON (`CD`.`categories_id` = `tableC`.`categories_id` OR `PTP`.`categories_id` = `CD`.`categories_id`)
        WHERE 
                `orders_id` >= 80000 
            AND 
                `orders_id` <= 80010 
        GROUP BY 
            `orders_id`
```

Answer (score 1):

as you are selecting the same colums from the same table you could use [Union](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html).
you could even Group by orders_id in the outer sql:

```
(SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1)
UNION
(SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2)
GROUP BY orders_id
```

but within PHP it is not possible to do 2 queries with one request, you have to form your sql-query